# Nouns in sentences

Tags: gender, personal-pronoun

Which of the following ways is the right way to write this sentence?:

> Die offene Küche ist sehr geräumig und modern, obwohl **sie**
>   unordentlich ist.

OR

> Die offene Küche ist sehr geräumig und modern, obwohl **es**
>   unordentlich ist.

Comment: Beide nicht. "Obwohl" sagt man nur, wenn die eine Aussage wie ein Widerspruch zur anderen wirkt, etwa: "Obwohl er montags noch vollkommen gesund wirkte ist er am Dienstag gestorben." Größe und Modernität stehen aber nicht im Widerspruch zu Unordnung.

Answer (score 4):

The first one. In German you refer to objects indirectly as their gender when the object is already mentioned.

> Als ich mich in den Stuhl gesetzt habe, ist er sofort kapput gegangen 
>   Ich liebte die Küche, nachdem die Frau mir sie gezeigt hat

With neutral nouns you can just use es / das. You also use the gendered determinate article when referring to nouns as well. For example:

> Das ist der Stuhl, den ich gestern gesehen habe

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's the first sentence

> Die offene Küche ist sehr geräumig und modern, obwohl **sie** unordentlich ist.

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Comment: I'm not sure but as far as I know, you have to use a _bestimmter Artikel_ when you know what is messy and a _unbestimmter Artikel_ when not

Comment: @EliasDolinsek Abgesehen davon, dass der Satz wegen des falschen Gebrauchs von _obwohl_ immer noch nicht richtig ist, verstehe ich Ihre Erwiderung auf Jankas Kommentar nicht. Was haben bestimmte und unbestimmte Artikel (der, die, das, ein, eine, ...) mit der Frage zu tun?